# Query string in a mod_rewrite rule (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

If I have a question mark in my `q=` Parameter, the `.htaccess` is redirect me to the 404 error-page.

This is my .htaccess Rewrite-Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Does anybody know how I can allow a question mark in the get parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead. It will handle all all requests to `search/`. From three paths—as your example shows—to one path:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/search/([a-z0-9]+)/?([^/]*)$ /results.php?q=$1&$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^/search/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /results.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/search/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /results.php?q=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/search/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /results.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Or try this without the `/` at the front of the URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9]+)/?([^/]*)$ results.php?q=$1&$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ results.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ results.php?q=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ results.php?q=$1 [L]
```

This second one works on my local MAMP setup. If I create a `results.php` whose contents are this:

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

And then load the following URL; which I based off of your comment which states you got an error with `/search/google/0/web`:

```
 http://localhost:8888/search/google/0/web
```

This is result I get in my browser:

```
Array
(
    [q] => google
    [start] => 0
    [type] => web
)
```

Comment: I got this error message: "The requested URL /search/google/0/web was not found on this server."

Comment: The next fail is the undefined GET-type, if i put a questiontake in the url. You know why ? `(www.example.com/search/google/0 ?/0/web)`